# Can't find v7 Preference Support Library in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm currently using **Eclipse ADT 23.0.7** for android app development. My SDK manager is updated for **Android 6.0** shown in below.
[image].
I want to use **v7 Preference Support Library** in my project. but, unfortunately I can't found it in my **(sdk)/extras/android/support/v7** directory as stated in [Android Developer Website](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-preference).[image]
 I can't figure out what to do. Thanks in advance for any kind of help!
**UPDATE 1**
I've also tried to re-download the library but, nothing happen. Preference library is still missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google stopped to provide Eclipse projects. It pushes developers to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio. So all libraries are available as *.aar files

But it is still possible to these files in Eclipse.
Find the aar for your library at `\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\preference-v7\23.0.1\`

Then use instructions from CommonsWare guy [Consuming AARs from Eclipse](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html):

> 1. UnZIP the AAR into some directory.
> 2. Create an empty directory that will be the home for the Android
>      library project. For the rest of these steps, I will refer to this as
>      “the output directory”.
> 3. Copy the AndroidManifest.xml, res/, and assets/ directories from the
>      AAR into the output directory.
> 4. Create a libs/ directory in the output directory. Copy into libs/ the
>      classes.jar from the root of the unZIPped AAR, plus anything in libs/
>      in the AAR (e.g., mediarouter-v7 has its own JAR of proprietary bits).
> 5. Decide what build SDK you want to try to use. You might just choose
>      the highest SDK version you have installed. Or, you can use the
>      android:minSdkVersion and the -vNN resource set qualifiers to get
>      clues as to what a good build SDK might be. If desired, create a
>      project.properties file with a target=android-NNN line, where NNN is
>      your chosen build SDK. Or, you can address this in Eclipse later on.
> 6. Import the resulting project into Eclipse, and if needed adjust the
>      build SDK (Project > Properties > Android). Also, you will need to
>      attach to this library project any library projects it depends upon
>      (e.g., mediarouter-v7 depends upon appcompat-v7).

Comment: Thanks for providing this useful information. but, I've found eclipse based project from [here](https://github.com/kasim1011/android-support-v7-preference).