# PreferenceFragmentCompat not found on Eclipse

Tags: android, android-support-library, preference-v7

Android already has a library to support PreferenceFragment in older versions. I'm not using Android Studio so I can't add to the gradle:

```
com.android.support:preference-v7:23.0.0
```

I already have the latest version of the support library **23.0.1**, but for some reason the project did not appear on the **sdk/extras/android/support/v7** folder, so i can´t import it. Is possible to get the library in some way or i need to migrate the project to AndroidStudio?

Comment: See also [this apparent conversion of the `preference-v7` AAR into a library project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498736/cant-find-v7-preference-support-library-in-eclipse-adt).